# Use a JSON with JSONOBJECT in Java

Tags: json

I want to use the following JSON in my code in Java:

```
[
 {
  "speed": 200
 }
]
```

I tried to write this line :

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject("[{\"speed\": 200}]");
```

But I always get an error. What is the exact format that I have to use here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: So it would be more proper to use a JSONArray rather than use a JSONObject (as my last post said)

So the correct java code would be

```
    String json = "[{\"speed\": 200}]";
    System.out.println(json);
    JSONArray jsonBody = new JSONArray(json);
    System.out.println(jsonBody.getJSONObject(0).get("speed"));
```

Comment: It was no that easy. I use an SDK which oblige me to respect this format. It's in fact an array of json, it's why it started by "[". But in my case, I'm only interested in the first json. And I don't know how can I write this json without modifiying the first format..

Comment: Edited my answer to better reflect your situation.